# How do I connect my tab bar icon to my screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I created a tab bar on XCode and I added a home icon but I need to know how to connect that home icon to the screen I am on now ,so when I am on the home screen the home icon will be highlighted

Comment: Sorry,but I still don't understand. Where did you get the arrows and what does "two image set 1) selected 2)Non-selected" mean?

Comment: check below image upper-right side "Tab bar Item" in Selected Image "Bar Item" in Image

Answer (score 1):

two Image set

1)Selected

2)Non Selected

[image]